# Terraform Provisioner "local-exec" not working as expected | VPC Peering Connection Accept issue

Tags: networking, automation, aws-cli, terraform, amazon-vpc

I'm unable to get the auto accept peering done through the work around mentioned in the link ([Why am I getting a permissions error when attempting to auto_accept vpc peering in Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450250/why-am-i-getting-a-permissions-error-when-attempting-to-auto-accept-vpc-peering)"] via provisioner option

See below Terraform code of mine. Can some one help me out?

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "default"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "peer"
  alias   = "peer"
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "peer" {
  provider = "aws.peer"
}



resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "service-peer" {
  vpc_id                            = "vpc-123a56789bc"

  peer_vpc_id                       = "vpc-YYYYYY"
  peer_owner_id                     = "012345678901"
  peer_region                       = "us-east-1"


  accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }

  requester {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 accept-vpc-peering-connection --vpc-peering-connection-id=${aws_vpc_peering_connection.service-peer.id} --region=us-east-1 --profile=peer"
  }

}
```

Output I'm getting:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_vpc_peering_connection.servicehub-peer: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_vpc_peering_connection.servicehub-peer: Unable to modify peering options. The VPC Peering Connection "pcx-08ebd316c82acacd9" is not active. Please set `auto_accept` attribute to `true`, or activate VPC Peering Connection manually.

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure
```

Where as I'm able to run the aws cli command successfully via linux shell, outside the terraform template. Let me know if I'm missing out something in the terraform script.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Does it error?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - I update the output of the terraform template

Answer (score 0):

Try with moving out your "local-exec" and add depends on link with your VPC peering.

```
resource "null_resource" "peering-provision" {
  depends_on = ["aws_vpc_peering_connection.service-peer"]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 accept-vpc-peering-connection --vpc-peering-connection-id=${aws_vpc_peering_connection.service-peer.id} --region=us-east-1 --profile=peer"
  }
}
```

As said Koe it's may be better to use auto_accept option.

Comment: @frbyart - auto_accept option won't work for Cross Account VPC peering. See the documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc_peering.html#auto_accept

Comment: @frbyart - I also, tried moving out local-exec as mentioned by you but still throwing the same error.

Comment: Can any one help me out on this issue?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer because I was wrong, as @cinny said, won't work for Cross Accounts VPC peering.